# Do 2D lists get edited when you call a modifying function inside an if logic statement?

Tags: python, list

The question title may be hard to understand. But let's assume that I have a 2D 8x8 list called `chessboard`:

```
chessboard = [[0 for x in range(n)]for y in range(n)]
```

And I have a function which adds a knight piece to the specific index.

```
def add_white_knight(chessboard, a, b):
    chessboard[a][b] = 1
    return chessboard
```

And I have function called `attack_configuration` which only checks if a specific board configuration satisfies some specific rules.

So, what I want to do is, before adding a piece to my board, check if it satisfies the required configuration.

My attempt was to do

```
if(attack_configuration(add_black_knight(chessboard, i, j))):
    chessboard = add_black_knight(chessboard, i, j)
```

But I realized that this fails because the `chessboard` already gets edited inside the `if` statement. What could be a practical solution to this tiny issue?

Thanks.

Comment: A possible solution could be to send a copy of chessboard, `if .....(chessboard.copy(), i,j))):`

Comment: Ummm, first check with `if attack_configuration(chessboard):` ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean that you want to test different possible configuration with your black knight in different positions before choosing the "right one" and making the move for good on the chessboard?

Comment: @RaunaqJain `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @zwer well the point is that I want to check if I placing the knight piece would satisfy the required conditions before actually placing it

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes. I want to place a knight piece to anywhere which satisfies some conditions. But before doing so, I have to check if placing the piece in the square would cause a problem.

Comment: @Huzo can you recheck if you added `()` at the end of copy like, `copy()`?